# Cannot print polygons filled with hatches with Geoserver print

Tags: printing, leaflet, fill, geoserver

I have a chloropleth map built with Leaflet, showing polygons filled with hatches thanks to the plugin leaflet-polygon.fillPattern.js and it works fine.

```
function myStyle (feature)  {
        return {
            fill: 'url(assets/img/image.png)',
            fillColor: '#6677cd',
            weight: 7,
            opacity: 1,
            fillOpacity: 1
        }
    }  

    var layer = new L.geoJson(data,{
        style:myStyle 
    });
```

I can print my map with Geoserver print and the leaflet.print plugin, but the problem is that my printed map only show my polygons filled with color and not with my pattern.

I checked in the spec Json I'm sending to Geoserver print, and it shows that fill in feature's options is set well:

```
fill:"url(assets/img/image.png)"
```

I tried with both png and svg images, and both are not displayed.

Any idea why my printed map is not rendering the hatches in my polygons ?

Here is the SLD code when I tried to send my polygon's style in Geoserver

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" 
xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.1.0" 
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld 
http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" 
xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se">
  <NamedLayer>
    <se:Name>PSC_Surf</se:Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <se:Name>PSC_Surf</se:Name>
      <se:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>Single symbol</se:Name>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#ffff00</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#000001</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel
</se:SvgParameter>
        </se:Stroke>
      </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
      <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        <se:Fill>
          <se:GraphicFill>
            <se:Graphic>
              <se:Mark>
                    <se:WellKnownName>horline</se:WellKnownName>
                    <se:Stroke>
                      <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#5c00b8</se:SvgParameter>
                      <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">3</se:SvgParameter>
                    </se:Stroke>
                  </se:Mark>
                  <se:Size>11</se:Size>
                  <se:Rotation>
                    <ogc:Literal>45</ogc:Literal>
                  </se:Rotation>
                </se:Graphic>
              </se:GraphicFill>
            </se:Fill>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
      </se:FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

To be more precise,  my problem is about why Geoserver print module is not rendering the fill style I'm calling in leaflet thanks to the leaflet-polygon.fillPattern.js with the style option 
     fill: 'url(assets/img/image.png)',

For markers layers, I can call my icons and send them to the Geoserver print module in the spec JSON with that :

```
var iconUrl = icon.options.iconUrl;
style = {externalGraphic: this._getAbsoluteUrl(iconUrl)};
```

So that, I tried for my polygons with :
    style = {graphicFill: url(assets/img/image.png)};

But it doesn't works

Comment: can GeoServer see "assets/img/image.png" ?

Comment: Yes, I have icons in the same folder and it works with icons and externalGraphics

Comment: does it work if you style the polygons in GeoServer?

Comment: I just tried to export my polygon's style I had first in Qgis, and export my style in SLD. Then, I applied this style in Geoserver and I cannot see the hatches ...

Comment: please add the relevant part of the SLD to the question

Comment: I've edited my post with the SLD

Answer (score 1):

GeoServer doesn't recognise `horline` as a well-known shape, as [documented here](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/extensions/pointsymbols.html#shape-symbols) you need to use `shape://horline`.

Comment: Ok, thanks @Ian Turton, I'll try that in my second option, styling my layer with SLD in Geoserver and call it as a WMS layer in Leaflet. But my question was quite different, I'll edit my post to be more precise

Comment: You need to add the SLD that the print plugin generates then

Comment: It works indeed to style my polygons with SLD, thanks Ian. But it still not solve my problem when I want to print my wfs layer displayed with leaflet, my printed map still not display the hatches

Comment: as I  said, you need to look at the SLD that the print plugin sends to GeoServer then put that in the question.